# Install bpftrace on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, ebpf, bpftrace

I am new at eBPF and i am following the bpftrace installing quide of https://github.com/iovisor/bpftrace. After cloning it and
`mkdir bpftrace/build; cd bpftrace/build;`
I have executed build-libs.sh
`~/bpftrace/build$ ../build-libs.sh`
So the script is unable to find the necessary files and directories to compile and install the BPFTrace libraries. The output of the last command execution is the following

```
~/bpftrace/build$ ../build-libs.sh   
+++ realpath ./build-libs.sh
++ dirname /home/me/bpftrace/build-libs.sh
+ BPFTRACE_DIR=/home/me/bpftrace
+ DESTDIR=/home/me/bpftrace/build-libs
+ mkdir -p /home/me/bpftrace/build-libs
+ [[ ! -n '' ]]
++ which gcc
+ [[ -n /usr/bin/gcc ]]
+ CC=gcc
++ nproc
+ make -C /home/me/bpftrace/libbpf/src -j4 CC=gcc OBJDIR=/home/me/bpftrace/build-libs PREFIX=/home/me/bpftrace/build-libs install install_uapi_headers
make: *** /home/me/bpftrace/libbpf/src: No such file or directory.  Stop.
```

Comment: Looks like you have not yet pulled the submodules, this can be done with `git submodule init && git submodule update --recursive`. Source: https://github.com/iovisor/bpftrace/blob/master/INSTALL.md#vendored-libraries

Comment: @DylanReimerink Probably worth making this into a full-fledged answer.

Comment: Yes, of course.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pull the submodules step when Building bpftrace on Ubuntu

`git submodule init && git submodule update --recursive`

This will initialize the vendored libraries.